# "Snap an image" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Does MATLAB have a function that will "snap an image" or move an image to some predefined location if within a certain area?

Comment: Do you mean capture an image? crop an image? Do you want to search for an image within a certain area of an image and then do something with the found image? Try to elaborate on exactly what you are desiring to do.

Comment: She's talking about the "snap-on" feature prevalent in several GUIs. It will "snap" into place based on the area it's in, e.g. if you drag a Figure window into the MATLAB desktop, it'll "snap-on" to the top-left area.

Answer (score 0):

[`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html)